# jQuery Nearest H2 value that's non parent/child

Tags: jquery, google-tag-manager

I need to find the `h2` value closest to the click. However, the `h2` is sat in the sibling of the parent `div`. There are multiple `div` with various `h2` values. If a link is clicked I need the closest `h2` value.

```
<div class="daddy">
    <div class="sibling-1">
        <h2>Sibling 1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="sibling-2">
        <a href="/1">link 1</a>
        <a href="/2">link 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="sibling-3">
        <h2>Sibling 3</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="sibling-4">
        <a href="/3">link 3</a>
        <a href="/4">link 4</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

So I need it that if `link 1` is clicked then `Sibling 1` is returned. If `link 4` is clicked then `Sibling 3` is returned.

I don't have access to the clients code as this is for a GTM implementation.

I've tried `jQuery({{Click Element}}).closest('.daddy').find('h2').text();` but this returned `Sibling 1 Sibling 3`.

**EDIT**

Forgot to include that there are some circumstances whereby the `h2` and/or the link are in multiple deeper divs e.g.

```
<div class="daddy">
    <div class="sibling-1">
        <div class="deep-1">
            <h2>Sibling 1</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sibling-2">
        <div class="deep-1">
            <div class="deep-2">
                <a href="/1">link 1</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="/2">link 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="sibling-3">
        <h2>Sibling 3</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="sibling-4">
        <a href="/3">link 3</a>
        <a href="/4">link 4</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the `h2` always in the immediately previous DIV, or can there be other DIVs between them?

Comment: There can be others in the way too.

Comment: It would be best if you showed that in the question, so people don't post answers that assume they're adjacent like the examples you gave.

Comment: Could the closest one be in a DIV after the link, or is always before? E.g. is sibling 3 closer to link 2?

Comment: Always the one above is required. Have updated the question to show multiple div levels.

Comment: So the depth can be deeper, but it's still the immediately preceding sibling.

Comment: Can you give a common class to all the `sibling-X` DIVs? Otherwise, it's hard to know how far up to go from the link to find the element whose siblings to look in.

Comment: You have a bunch of typos in the added HTML, where `<div>` should be `</div>`.

Comment: Why is this tagged with "Google Tag Manager" ?

Comment: It's tagged with GTM as this is where it's going to be used and in case anyone already had something similar in GTM

Answer (score 2):

This code should work.

First it uses `parentsUntil` to find all the enclosing DIVs until the `.daddy`, and gets the last one to find the DIV whose siblings to search. To make things clearer, I suggest you give all those DIVs a common class, so you could just use .closest(".classname")` to find that DIV.

From there, `prevAll` finds all the DIVs before it that contain an `h2` element, takes the first of those (which will be the closest because they're returned in order of distance), and then finds the `h2` element within it.

```js
$("a").click(function() {
  var containingDiv = jQuery(this).parentsUntil(".daddy").last();
  var prevDivs = containingDiv.prevAll("div:has(h2)");
  var h2 = prevDivs.first().find("h2");
  alert(h2.text());

  return false;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="daddy">
  <div class="sibling-1">
    <div class="deep-1">
      <h2>Sibling 1</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sibling-2">
    <div class="deep-1">
      <div class="deep-2">
        <a href="/1">link 1</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="/2">link 2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="sibling-3">
    <h2>Sibling 3</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="sibling-4">
    <a href="/3">link 3</a>
    <a href="/4">link 4</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Would this work is the `h2`and link were inside another `div`? e.g. `<div class="sibling-1"><div class="sub"><h2>Sibling 1</h2></div></div>` and `<div class="sibling-2"><div><a href="/1">link 1</a><a href="/2">link 2</a></div></div>`

Comment: Yes. `:has()` searches inside the element to any level of nesting.

Comment: My tests are returning [object Object]. Any ideas?

Comment: That sounds like you're printing the object instead of its text.

Comment: Added .`.text()` to the end and now there's nothing.

Comment: Thanks, modified to the following so it works in Google Tag Manager. `function() {
  var containingDiv = jQuery({{Click Element}}).parentsUntil(".daddy").last();
  var prevDivs = containingDiv.prevAll("div:has(h2)");
  var h2 = prevDivs.first().find("h2");
  return h2.text();
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
       $('a').on('click',function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).parent().prev().find('h2').text());
        return false;
});

});
```

Comment: The closest one might not be in the previous DIV.